# Is there an example of when DFS will not return the min. spanning tree?

Tags: graph-traversal, minimum-spanning-tree

If we have a connected, weighted, undirected graph. Can anyone provide an example where DFS will not return the MST? No matter what vertex we start from ?

Comment: Please add what you tried to convince yourself that there are no such graphs, or find one.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one such example of undirected weighted graph.

[image]